# undifined index error php but why

Tags: php

So I have been converting a file from mysql to mysqli, so when I open the file in localhost, I get this error:

**Notice**: Undefined index: name in **C:\xampp\htdocs\mafiagametest\Safe.php** on line **80**

This is line 80:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM crimetimes WHERE name='". mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name'])."'";
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: `$_POST['name']` is not set

Comment: i think the error is pretty straight forward. do a `var_dump($_POST)` to check if `$_POST`  has an element with key : 'name'

Comment: this variable is meant to be filled by submitting a form via http post method. Inspect your http headers to see it's not there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because 'name' isn't set, or, 'name' is being used in a place that can be null. It's a notice from PHP to tell you to fix this because it could produce unexpected results.

To fix this;

```
<?php
$name = (isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : die("Missing a name!");
```

Then run your escape on `$name`.
By the way, check out [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Much easier way to handle user inputted data.